# Why do Ryanair not use jetways?

Tags: passenger, boarding, ryanair

Whilst flying into London's Stanstead Airport the other day I noticed that despite there being many jetways available Ryanair weren't using them for any of their planes. Instead, they'd chosen to have pairs of staircases at either end of the plane. The same is also true when they are operating out of other airports where jetways are available.

Is this just done for speed or might there be other reasons for making this decision?

Comment: This article seems to confirm your hypothesis, but also suggests that airports charge more for using jetbridges. I've also noticed that some (all?) Ryanair aircraft have airstairs for the front door, which they deploy as quickly as possible, precluding the use of a jetbridge. http://www.traveller.com.au/ryanair-slashes-flights-after-row-over-stairs-1d3ie

Comment: I vote to re-open this question. The other question is about airlines in general. This one is about Ryanair, and the answer, like the answer to most questions about Ryanair, is "To humiliate their passengers." Anyone who has watched successive Ryanair flights disgorge their human cargo down slippery wet steps in driving, freezing rain and oblige them to walk across puddled tarmac with the wind raising huge sheets of water into the air, before doing the same in reverse to a fresh load of victims, will sense the truth of this.

Comment: I too really don't feel this is a duplicate of another question. The "duplicate" asks who decides where a plane gets put, mine asks a question about why a particular airline makes the descision to nevwr use jetways for their flights.

Comment: I agree it shouldn't have been a duplicate, it just needed extra clarification in the body as to why it's different, anyway the same question was asked again recently, this time about easyJet, and it's been answered: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/54056/14897